# cURL doesn't give any response on PHP script

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm pretty new to PHP so any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is running on WAMP server with cURL enabled and is supposed to upload tracking for orders i'm trying to process. But when i run this script i don't get a response so i assume its broken somewhere however i don't get any errors so i'm unsure as to whats actually happening.

The problem seems to be cause but either the way I’m creating the $datatopost array or with the actual cURL part of my code I think.

```
if($_REQUEST)
{
    $supplier = $_REQUEST["supplier_ID"];
    $token = $_REQUEST["token"];
    $filePath = $_REQUEST["filePath"];
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["fileName"];
}

$itemID = array();

$array = file($filePath.$fileName);
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $temp = explode(",",$value);

    $itemID[] = array( "carrier" => $temp[1], "ci_lineitem_id" => $temp[0], "tracking" => $temp[2]);
}

$datatopost = array (
"supplier_id" => $supplier,
"token" => $token,
"tracking_info" =>json_encode($itemID)
);

$ch = curl_init ("https://scm.commerceinterface.com/api/v2/tracking_notification");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);

if( $response ) 
{
    $response_json = json_decode( $response );

    if( $response_json['success'] == true ) 
    {
        file_put_contents($filePath."Success.txt", $response);
    } 
    else 
    {
        file_put_contents($filePath."Failed.txt", $response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents($filePath."Success.txt", $responce);

file_put_contents($filePath."Failed.txt", $responce);
```

I think the variable $responce in the file_put_contents() method is unknown. Try to use **$response**.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that but that could have caused problems later so thanks. But unfortunatly it doen't fix the problem i'm having.

Comment: Did you try to print the cURL result ? (echo $response; just after this line "$response = curl_exec ($ch);" )

Comment: using this line instead of the echo returns a blank txt  file (file_put_contents($filePath."Test.txt", $response);) so it seems that $response is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get a SSL secured site, so take a look at the CURLOPT_SSL_* options:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php.

For detailed information, you should check the cURL result (like already mentioned).

Comment: I'm following the layout outlined on this page https://scm.commerceinterface.com/api-doc/v2/ under tracking notification. As I said I'm new to php especially cURL (I only got this far because it similar to C#) but I wouldn’t know what to do with the CURLOPT_SSL_* for the site I’m trying to access.

And unfortunately the cURL result ($response) seems to be null when I use file_put_contents($filePath."Test.txt", $response); I just get a blank .txt file.